# Выполнение скрипта при нажатии

Tags: javascript, html, html5

[image: ФОТКА]

Хочу сделать что бы при нажатии на какой-либо объект запускался js код который ранее будет добавлен в папку сайта либо что бы исполнялось действие из тега `<script src="example.com\script.js">`

Comment: Когда создаете вопрос используйте `блок кода` в виде текста, чтобы показать ваш код. Это легко воспроизводится и вы получите быстрый и емкий ответ. А может и сами сразу увидите ваши ошибки, такие как неверный тэг на вашей картинке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как уже сказал Виталий, надо писать непосредственно функцию. И не стоит использовать onclick. Напишите обработчик так:

HTML:

```
<button class="button">Run some code</button> <!-- добавил класс кнопке -->
```

JS:

```
const button = document.querySelector(".button");
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
     alert("Вы нажали на кнопку и запустили код!");
})
```

Comment: Спасибо, долго искал и ни один ответ не подошёл. Благодарю)

Answer (score 0):

Вам вместо "старт js кода" надо прописать непосредственно функцию, которая была ранее добавлена и которая будет выполняться. Или сразу прописать код

И обратите внимание, в теге <buuton у вас ошибка.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы понять, как это работает, сделайте так (но это не всегда правильно)

```js
function myFunc() {
  alert("Привет, мир!");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunc()"></button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример) Благодарю за поддержку.